# How do I figure out why "Verify Installation" is failing in CouchDB on macOS?

Tags: macos, couchdb, macos-ventura, fauxton

**What I'm struggling with:**

From the official CouchDB docs page, I first followed the steps [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/mac.html) to install the Apache CouchDB native application. When doing "Verify Installation" in Fauxton as it said, it brought up this error:

[Image: Screenshot of Fauxton showing an X under the status for "Create View", along with a message saying "Error: internal_server_error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owxnc.png)

I wasn't sure what that meant, so I just jumped ahead to [this](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/tour.html) "Tutorial" page, which had a section that said, "If any [tests] fail, re-check your installation steps."

But I went through the steps I followed on the first page, and I still have no clue what to fix. I've tried searching for what this error could mean, but I haven't found any resources that aren't either seemingly unrelated or horribly vague. And because I'm using CouchDB for the first time, I have no clue what to look for in its logs.

Where should I start to go about fixing this error?

**Things I tried:**

I understood "re-checking the installation steps" as just going back over the installation-steps list and checking whether I did them all. So, all I ended up doing was rerunning "Verify Installation" in Fauxton several times like a fool....

I also tried going to the ["Setup"](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/setup/index.html#setup) link on the "Installation" page, because I realized I hadn't done that. I followed the instructions to set up a single node, then went and did "Verify Installation" again. I was expecting that at least there would now be a check mark next to "Create Views", but the error message looks exactly the same.

Another thing I did, following [this](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/troubleshooting.html#macos-known-issues) page I found, was run `brew install nspr` and see if maybe installing this dependency could clear up this error. Same expected-vs-reality as above.

Comment: same thing happening to me on Mac Mini with OS X 10.15.7 
Updated CouchDB to 3.3.1 and it ruined my whole setup now I can't run anything dependent on couchDB and can't find the previous version to download

Comment: MacBook Air, M2, Ventura 13.3 - log has a bazillion lines like: `[info] 2023-04-03T21:47:35.085573Z couchdb@localhost <0.285.0> -------- couch_proc_manager <0.2440.66> died normal` and 
`[error] 2023-04-03T21:47:35.087808Z couchdb@localhost <0.1084.2> -------- OS Process Error <0.2436.66> :: {os_process_error,{exit_status,134}}` -- still looking for errors related to verification

Comment: Then comes these periodically: `[notice] 2023-04-03T21:47:36.704679Z couchdb@localhost <0.401.0> -------- chttpd_auth_cache changes listener died because the _users database does not exist. Create the database to silence this notice.` followed by two *too long for here* items relating to `shards...`

Comment: The verification process had `[info]` lines about using `GET` and `DELETE` with `verifytestdb` and `verifytestdb/_design/view_check` with `404` and `401` messages, followed by `PUT` with `verifytestdb/test_doc_10`, `20`, and `30` - and similar result codes. -- It looks like some files are missing, perhaps?

Comment: Just submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/4510) on the Apache/couchdb GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed in CouchDB 3.2.3 and 3.3.2 released today:

- https://blog.couchdb.org/2023/04/25/3-2-3-3-3-2/
- https://github.com/janl/build-couchdb-mac/commit/8dad21c257e307e7feae7ca6dd86d778ac7d624f

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Apparently [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is necessary for using CouchDB on a Mac. I was informed that installing [Spidermonkey](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/js/build.html) [via brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/spidermonkey#default) would fix the verification problem.

---

I stopped the missing `_users` table messages by performing the steps [in the last post, by @jonathanwork, of this Fauxton issue report](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/4372). At the Terminal do these commands:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://admin:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/_replicator'

curl -X PUT 'http://admin:pass@127.0.0.1:5984/_users'
```

Make sure they return `{"ok":true}`.

---

*However*, that does *not* fix the verification process.

In my [Fauxton issue report, @whosnorman](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/4510), suggested using [a prior version of CouchDB retrieved from the Wayback Machine](https://couchdb.neighbourhood.ie/downloads/3.2.2/mac/3.2.2-1/Apache-CouchDB.zip) - link goes directly to the `zip` file for version 3.2.2 - saying that worked for them.